# Ruby Problemewith filter and RSpec

Tags: testing, rspec, controller, posts

I can't figure out why this `RSpec` test fails. Any advice?
I try to handle the destruction of post. Only users who create posts can delete them.

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authorized_user, :only => :destroy

def destroy
  post = Post.find(params[:id])
  post.destroy
  redirect_to posts_path, notice: 'Post successfully destroyed'
end

private  
 def authorized_user
  redirect_to posts_path, notice: 'Access Denied' if current_user.posts.find_by_id(params[:id]).nil?
end
```

Test :

```
describe "DELETE destroy" do
 before(:each) do
   @post = stub_model(Post, :id => 23)
   @post.stub(:destroy){true}
   Post.stub(:find){@post}
 end
 it "should search the post" do
  Post.should_receive(:find).with(@post.id.to_s).and_return(@post)
  delete :destroy, {:id => @post.id }
 end

 it "should destroy the post" do
  @post.should_receive(:destroy)
  delete :destroy, {:id => @post.id }
 end
 it "should redirect to the posts list" do
  delete :destroy, {:id => @post.id }
  response.should redirect_to posts_path
 end
end
```

And errors :

```
  1) PostsController DELETE destroy should search the post
 Failure/Error: Post.should_receive(:find).with(@post.id.to_s).and_return(@post)
   (<Post(id: integer, title: string, body: text, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, user_id: integer) (class)>).find("23")
       expected: 1 time
       received: 0 times
 # ./spec/controllers/posts_controller_spec.rb:67:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because in the before(:each) block you have to log in a user. You have before_filter and this filter is only for :destroy. So when you don't have a logged in user then your tests will fail because it is actually a user without permissions that "runs the test". So you should put this code in before(:each):

```
user = way_to_make_user - I do it with: FactoryGirl.create(:user,role=>"client")
controller.sign_in user
```

I could help you more if you tell me what do you use for authentication. I use cancan gem. So the main point is that you have to log in user before each test.